# FastAPI type hint error in Dependency during unit testing

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi, pydantic

I'm encountering a type hint error (Invalid args for response field) in FastAPI when using a dependency. This issue only arises during unit testing.

Endpoint:

```py
@router.get(
    '/me/account/user',
    response_model=schemas.User,
)
async def account_user(user: Annotated[schemas.User, Depends(prepare_user)]):
    return user.dict()
```

Dependency:

```py
async def prepare_user(
    request: Request,
    db: Annotated[AsyncSession, Depends(async_get_db)]
) -> schemas.User:
    """Create a user if it does not exist, otherwise return the user"""

    external_id = request.state.user.claims.get("sub")

    user = await crud.get_user_by_external_id(db=db, external_id=external_id)
    if not user:
        user_in = schemas.UserCreate(external_id=external_id, is_active=True)
        user = await crud.create_user(db=db, user=user_in)

    user = schemas.User.from_orm(user)

    return user
```

My conftest.py for Pytest:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
async def db() -> AsyncSession:
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
async def normal_client():
    """Fixture for a normal/non-admin user client."""

    async def override_async_get_db(db: AsyncSession) -> AsyncSession:
        try:
            yield db
        finally:
            await db.close()

    app.dependency_overrides[async_get_db] = override_async_get_db

    async def mock_normal_user(request: Request):
        user = B2CUser(
            iss='iss',
            iat=1,
            nbf=2,
            exp=3,
            sub='sub',
            ver='2.0',
            claims={
                'sub': 'sub'
            },
            aud='aud',
            tid='tid',
            access_token='123',
        )
        request.state.user = user
        return user

    app.dependency_overrides[azure_scheme] = mock_normal_user
    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url='http://test') as c:
        yield c
    app.dependency_overrides = {}
```

My test case:

```py
async def test_endpoint(normal_client: AsyncClient):
   response = await normal_client.get('/me/account/user')
   assert response.status_code == 200
```

Error:

```
fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field!
Hint: check that <class 'sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.session.AsyncSession'> is a valid Pydantic field type. 
If you are using a return type annotation that is not a valid Pydantic field (e.g. Union[Response, dict, None]) you can disable generating the response model from the type annotation with the path operation decorator parameter response_model=None. 
Read more: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/
```

While many of my tests work (those not using the prepare_user dependency), this specific test fails. However, when I test the app using the openAPI client, it functions correctly and returns the expected user details.

Versions:

```
fastapi             0.97.0
pydantic            1.10.12
pytest              7.4.0
pytest-asyncio      0.21.1

Python              3.11.4
```

I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this type hint error during unit testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `conftest.py` I was passing `db: AsyncSession` on the `override_async_get_db` function, but it should be passed in the `normal_client` function. Corrected `conftest.py`:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
async def db() -> AsyncSession:
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
async def normal_client(db: AsyncSession): # added here
    """Fixture for a normal/non-admin user client."""

    async def override_async_get_db() -> AsyncSession: # removed here
        try:
            yield db
        finally:
            await db.close()

    app.dependency_overrides[async_get_db] = override_async_get_db

    async def mock_normal_user(request: Request):
        user = B2CUser(
            iss='iss',
            iat=1,
            nbf=2,
            exp=3,
            sub='sub',
            ver='2.0',
            claims={
                'sub': 'sub'
            },
            aud='aud',
            tid='tid',
            access_token='123',
        )
        request.state.user = user
        return user

    app.dependency_overrides[azure_scheme] = mock_normal_user
    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url='http://test') as c:
        yield c
    app.dependency_overrides = {}
```

this lead to the currently only pytest case using the `normal_client` fixtures failing.